Xcode error from react native ViewManager not in scope
I am developing an app with react native and so far i have tried to work with Expo Go and everything has worked fine. However when trying to download the app to my phone for testing, and going through Xcode i have been getting this error with one of my expo modules. Specifically the ExpoMaps module. It says that cannot find View Manager in scope. Any solutions or alternatives??
enter image description here
I am trying to deploy my app on my phone for testing
